# Select Union SQL

Tags: sql, select, union

I am using the following query  :

```
select 8 Union Select 0 Union Select 15
```

to populate the these 3 number in a column.  The result I get is:

```
0  
8  
15
```

But I want 8 to come first and then 0 and then 15, e.g.

```
8  
0  
15
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want these in a particular order?  The rest of SQL won't consider them ordered, upon querying the table they've been placed in.  Heck, I wouldn't even rely on the insert order with an auto-generated key to be exactly what you expect (because if the system can make the inserts in parallel, you throw any potential ordering out the window).  If you absolutely need them in a specific order, you're probably better of adding an 'ordering' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UNION ALL
E.g.

```
select 8 UNION ALL Select 0 UNION ALL Select 15
```

Comment: Pleased to have helped. If I've answered your question could you mark it as the answer - there should be a tick for you to indicate this. That will help anyone else who finds your question know which of the responses solves things.

Answer (score 2):

@SimonMartin's answer works for the exact data set you give, but be aware that if your data set contains duplicate values, the `UNION ALL` will produce different results than `UNION`.

The `UNION` operator removes duplicates, whereas the `UNION ALL` will preserve them (as well as their order, as noted in @SimonMartin's answer).

If you want to combine the functionality of your `UNION` operator with the ordering capabilities provided by `UNION ALL`, then you need to start with `UNION ALL` then filter out the duplicate values yourself:

```
-- baseline query + 1 duplicate record at the end
with query as 
(
    select 8 as Val
        UNION ALL 
    Select 0 as Val
        UNION ALL 
    Select 15 as Val
        UNION ALL 
    Select 0 as Val
)
-- now add row numbers
, queryWithRowNumbers as 
(
    select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn, Val
    from query
)
-- finally, get rid of the duplicates
select Val from (
    select Val, min(rn) as minRn
    from querywithrownumbers
    group by val
) q
order by minRn
```

This will give results of

```
8
0
15
```

whereas if you ONLY use `UNION ALL` you will end up with

```
8
0
15
0
```